# Why Content-Length returning -1?

Tags: java

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://cuonline.ac.in/ranking/cap_admitted.php?clg=231").openConnection();
        System.out.println(conn.getContentLength());
```

Why it's returning the content length as `-1` ? Is am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That header might not be set for that page by the server, might not have finished loading when that statement executes and/or you might have connectivity issues.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29

As for your specific URL it looks like it's not set

```
SERVER RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date:
    Sun, 02 Aug 2015 16:02:49 GMT
Server:
    Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:
    PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.29
Vary:
    Accept-Encoding
Connection:
    close
Content-Type:
    text/html
```

http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/?page=single&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcuonline.ac.in%2Franking%2Fcap_admitted.php%3Fclg%3D231&useragent=1&typeProtocol=11

You may have to read the content conn.getInputStream() and count that instead.

Comment: I've good internet connection and i can see the Content-Length from my the RESTAPI Client (Chrome) but why can't with java. :(

Comment: Ok Mathew, let me try.

Comment: Mathew i did `conn.getInputStream().available()` and i got the content-length.

Comment: plus 1 for the `Server Header Checker`.

Comment: Excellent, must have been "might not have finished loading" then. .available() must wait for it to finish receiving.

There are probably better server header checkers than that site, it looks like that particular site hid the content-length header, "server header checker" is the generic term to Google for anyway :-).